# Override small-caps \chapter locally

Tags: xetex, titlesec, small-caps, textcase

When I customise the `\chapter` format using `titlesec` as follows (important bit is the `\bfseries` for small caps):

```latex
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{0pt}\Large\scshape\bfseries\centering}
    {\thesection\enspace}{0pt}{}[\vspace{2pt}{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}%
   {0mm}% How much of \titlerule line to remove from left
   {8mm}% Before \titlerule
   {0mm}% After \titlerule
```

and then in one `\chapter` title I’d like to change a word or two (plus points for possibility to include a `\\`) the case to lower-case, what should I do?

I’ve found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345546/latex-lowercase-a-single-letter-in-an-makeuppercase-environment) question, but I could not make it work. Not even the [`textcase`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) of @DavidCarlisle helped me.

Example headings:

```latex
\chapter*{Veľkonočná nedeľa\\ \MakeTextLowercase{alebo}\\ Nedeľa Pánovho zmŕtvychvstania}%

\chapter*{Sobota\\ \MakeTextLowercase{po Piatej pôstnej nedeli}}%
```

Comment: Would it be an unnumbered chapter?

Comment: In this particular case, yes. Otherwise, it would be nice to have as independent solution as possible (like loading a package). However, any solution is welcome. :)

Comment: You can use `\titleformat` inside the body of the document,, inside a group. For unnumbered chapters, you have the `numberless` key.

Comment: It is necessary to know what font package you're using.

Comment: @egreg, I use Libertinus Serif font (package `libertinus`), as use could see in all my other questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the “secondary shape” axis to standard; it is defined by the `fontaxes` package in order to allow for variations in small caps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{libertinus}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{0pt}\Large\scshape\bfseries\centering}
  {\thesection\enspace}
  {0pt}
  {}
  [\vspace{2pt}{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}%
   {0mm}% How much of \titlerule line to remove from left
   {8mm}% Before \titlerule
   {0mm}% After \titlerule

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax % just to make both titles go in the same page

\chapter*{Veľkonočná nedeľa\\ \textulc{alebo}\\ Nedeľa Pánovho zmŕtvychvstania}

\chapter*{Sobota\\ \textulc{po Piatej pôstnej nedeli}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With XeLaTeX you just need `\textup`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{0pt}\Large\scshape\bfseries\centering}
  {\thesection\enspace}
  {0pt}
  {}
  [\vspace{2pt}{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}%
   {0mm}% How much of \titlerule line to remove from left
   {8mm}% Before \titlerule
   {0mm}% After \titlerule

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\chapter*{Veľkonočná nedeľa\\ \textup{alebo}\\ Nedeľa Pánovho zmŕtvychvstania}

\chapter*{Sobota\\ \textup{po Piatej pôstnej nedeli}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You say to use `fontaxes` package, however, you did not included it in the example—have you forgotten it to include? :)

Comment: Indeed, from my tests, this code does not work without including `fontaxes`. And I was misleading in one one comments, when I said that I use `libertinus` package. I use that font, but I don’t include that as a package, but I use this command instead: `\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}`, for which we need to include `fontspec` package. The `textcase` package is not necessary.

Comment: @tukusejssirs You should be more specific. I assumed `pdflatex`.

Comment: I’m sorry, @egreg, however, *I* assumed you checked the tags. :)

Comment: @tukusejssirs The tag is there, but you said you use the package `libertinus`. Anyway, with fontspec it's even easier: use `\textup`.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, my mistake. Actually, I’ve never used a font package like that and never even used `pdflatex`. And the `\textup` solution is even better FWIW, although I could not find anything to solve my problem, when I search the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bernard suggested, I could use `\titleformat` anywhere in the document, not only in the preamble. So I simply created a new command (I named it `\chapterOther`), where I placed the `\titleformat` command without `\scshape`, then called the `\chapter`, and finally I re-formatted the `\chapter` with the original `\titleformat` command. All of this I placed into the preamble:

```latex
\newcommand{\chapterOther}[1]{%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{0pt}\Large\bfseries\centering}%
        {\thesection\enspace}{0pt}{}[\vspace{2pt}{\titlerule[1pt]}]%
    \titlespacing{\chapter}%
        {0mm}% How much of \titlerule line to remove from left
        {8mm}% Before \titlerule
        {0mm}% After \titlerule

    \chapter*{#1}%

    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
        {\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{0pt}\Large\scshape\bfseries\centering}
        {\thesection\enspace}{0pt}{}[\vspace{2pt}{\titlerule[1pt]}]
    \titlespacing{\chapter}%
        {0mm}% How much of \titlerule line to remove from left
        {8mm}% Before \titlerule
        {0mm}% After \titlerule
}
```

And then, when needed, I called it like this:

```latex
\chapterOther{\textsc{Veľkonočná nedeľa}\\ alebo\\ \textsc{Nedeľa Pánovho zmŕtvychvstania}}
```